How can I use Sharepoint Lists to create a Corrective Action Database
Good morning! I'm trying to use SharePoint to track RCA's (root cause analysis) and corrective actions.  Basically, I'd like to have a list that has the event, event description, facilitator etc. And then under each event, corrective actions assigned to various individuals.  I'm not sure the best way to do this that makes it easy to add/modify new events AND add/modify tasks.  Thoughts?

Typically the way to do this in SharePoint is via two lists and a lookup column to connect them.  For example, you'd create a list to hold the RCA Events, and then a second list of child corrective actions.  In the Corrective Action list, you'd have each corrective action, assigned to a user, and then set up the Parent Event column as a lookup to the RCA Events list.  You can then group the Corrective Actions list by Parent Event so you see each corrective action grouped under its parent event.
Example below:

Here is a reference to lookup columns that you can use to get started: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632
